# Modular building technique with angles? (A roof)

Tags: models

Ive been spending a bit of time lately studying the modular buildings of many games and reading/viewing several tutorials about it as well, but almost every example I see uses a plain square building that does not have any angled roof or similar.

In all my applications (CS6, Blender/Max, UDK) I adhere to the same grid spacing and I get pretty good results, but trying to make modular angled pieces is confusing me as I'm not sure the best way to approach it.

Below is some shots of my template sheet and workflow I have been doing. Should I do the roof separately or is it possible for me to keep it in the same texture sheet?

The main issue is below. I have made a couple modular roof pieces but when i try to use them, i end up needing to model multiple other parts to fill gaps based on what roof shape i want. I then model those 'filler' pieces and now i have that much less space left in my texture sheet and those pieces are usually not that reusable for anything else. This is where im not sure how to proceed.

If anyone has any links to documents or papers talking about this or advice, I would greatly appreciate it! =-)

My main roof pieces with the gaps
[image]

*My power of 2 texture sheet, with 16x16 grid squares.* 
[image]

*The texture sheet loaded into blender on a 16x16 plane and starting to separate and extrude.*
[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the problem is. When modeling tile systems I just look at legos. Pretty much everthing works as long as you are able to determine the right angle for each piece. I'm not really sure why you need filler bits. You should be able to make everything with a roof corner pyramid, roof side tube thingy (what you call "roof base"), a flat piece for the top, and I guess a chimney cube. Sorry if I am not really understanding the issue, but it doesn't look like you really have a problem with your system. Maybe you are just over thinking.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having trouble conceptualizing the modular pieces you need to create for buildings, I would recommend that you look to Lego. It will serve as both a practical example you can keep on your desk and is already highly modular.